# Access array inside a constructor

Tags: c#, arrays, constructor, stack, tdd

This Is for homework.

I have googled this and searched within stackoverflow, but I can not seem to find the answer. Perhaps my terminology is incorrect.

I am learning TDD for a class and my C# skills are rusty and limited.

***I am trying to write a stack class. When I try to initiate an array inside the constructor, the methods cannot access it.***

I'm sure it is something simple that I am missing.
Here is the code what i have tried so far :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace tdd_programmingTest
{
    class Stack
    {
        int index = 0;

        public Stack()
        {
            int[] items;
        }

        public void Push(int p)
        {
            items[index] = p;
            index++;
        }

        public int Pop()
        {
            index--;
            return items[index];
        }

        internal int IndexState()
        {
            return index;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me, just point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `int[] items;` outside of the constructor and add `size` parameter to the constructor to specify the size of `items`:

```
class Stack
{
    int index = 0;
    int[] items = new int[0];

    public Stack(int size)
    {
        items = new int[size]; // initiate items with size
    }

    public void Push(int p)
    {
        items[index] = p;
        index++;
    }

    public int Pop()
    {
        index--;
        return items[index];
    }

    internal int IndexState()
    {
        return index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but eventually I will need to add a parameter to the constructor to specify the size. As I understand, this method alone will not allow me to do that.

Comment: See my edited answer, you can add the `size` parameter to the constructor and initiate `items` with a specific size.

Comment: That was one of my original thoughts, but when I do that, Visual Studio puts a green line under _int[] items;_ explaining that it is never assigned.

Comment: See my edited answer again, you can avoid the green line by assigning the initial value to `new int[0]`, then its size will be changed when you call the constructor

Comment: After seeing your reply, I opened Visual Studio back up and the green line was gone without me setting the initial value or making any other modifications. Anyways, it works properly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

What you have here is a [**local variable**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664742.aspx):

```
    public Stack()
    {
        int[] items;
    }
```

It exits *only* inside of the `Stack()` constructor, and only for the lifetime of its execution.

You need to declare `items` as a [**field**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) (member variable):

```
class Stack
{
    private int index = 0;
    private int[] items;       // <-- move it here, and mark it private

    public Stack()
    {

    }
    // ...
}
```

But you have bigger problems. This is just a *reference* to an array which you haven't created yet.

So, you need to instantiate an array:

```
int[] items = new int[SIZE];
```

...but what size will you use?  Once you create the array, it can not grow. You'll have to allocate a larger array and copy it, once you run out of space.  This auto-self-expansion is how many [ADT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type)'s work under the hood.

Speaking of running out of space, you'd better pay attention to your array's bounds in `Push()` and `Pop()`!

---

EDIT: So you need to specify a size. Just add a parameter to the constructor.

```
class Stack
{
    private int index = 0;
    private int[] items;

    public Stack(int initialSize)
    {
        items = new int[initialSize];
    }

    public Stack() : Stack(100)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly. To my understanding, I would have to initiate the array inside the constructor so that I can pass a parameter for the size. This is where I am still having issues. I understand that my Push() and Pop() are incomplete. This TDD assignment is my first and requires me to write code and test it in very small increments.   EDIT: Or are you suggesting that if I start with an array with a size of one, I need to create a new array of one larger and copy the previous one into that every time I call Push()?

Comment: Many container classes will take an *optional* initial size parameter in their constructor, but default to something, say 10. Then, every time it becomes full (detected in `Push()`), you allocate a new array *twice as big*, and copy everything to the new array.

Comment: A requirement of the assignment is to declare a specific size every time it is initiated.

Comment: You are correct. I should have mentioned that. Thank you for your help.